# Eclipse plugin development - Putting a canvas into a editor window

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'd like to use the editor window in eclipse to display a canvas, I'm looking to be able to put together the same sort of funcationality as the visual editors (example below) [image]

My issue is that I don't really know where to start - I'm fairly happy writing plugins that do all manner of things, but I appear to be missing a trick here, can anyone point me at maybe:

a) the correct eclispe terms to be googling for (for example I did a lot better when I found out that what I wanted to do in eclipse was 'syntax colouring' not 'syntax highlighting'
b) a tutorial just showing how to put a picture in the space
c) some open-source thing with this functionality that I can inspect the code of

Answer (score 0):

You see those two tabs at the bottom of the editor labeled "Design" and "Source".  If you're doing something similar, you're designing an Eclipse multipage editor.

You'll need to start by extending the Eclipse class MultiPageEditorPart.

Here's an IBM article to get you started: [Building Eclipse plug-ins using templates](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclplgns/section9.html)